# How do you add a folder to the windows vista system environment path?

Tags: windows-vista, command-line-interface, systempath

so that I can execute apps (in cmd prompt) without specifying the fully qualified folder structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an admin,

- Go to Control Panel | System and click on Advanced System Settings in the left pane OR
- Right-click on Computer and choose Properties
- Click the Environment Variables button
- Under System Variables, edit the PATH variable and add your folder to the value (seperate with a semi-colon)

Comment: do I need to restart for it to take affect?

Comment: No, you shouldn't.  It is possible, however, that you'll need to restart certain services for them to pick up the change.  This isn't typically a big deal in a workstation OS, though, unless you're using it as a server.  You'll also need to close and reopen and cmd prompts that you have open at the time of the change.

Answer (score 1):

You can also modify them via the registry.  I find this useful when scripting some legacy programs that require certain environmental variables to function.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/104011